# Where to put main.go for a Go binary?

Tags: go, directory-structure

Lets say I have an awesome Go binary that denormalizes some data, and I'd like to place it under:

```
//some/path/denormalize/
```

Ideally my package name would be `denormalize` which would allow me to follow the guidelines for "[when] designing a package, consider how the two parts of a qualified identifier work together, not the member name alone".  Thus a potential member function might be `denormalize.FromX(...)`.  However, if I place the `main.go` for the denormalize binary under `denormalize/` package I can't use the intended package name as now the package would be named `main`.

Some options I've considered:

1. Place `main.go` under `denormalize/` and then place the rest of the code under `internal/` or `api/` or `pkg/`.  Pros: This seems to be what most folks do. Cons: The package name is not meaningful, and it violates the principle of insuring that the two parts of the qualifier work together since `api.FromX(...)` no longer makes sense.  This leads to more verbose names such as `api.DenormalizeFromX(...)`.
2. Place `main.go` under `denormalize/main/` and the rest of the code under `denormalize/`.  Pros: Package name stays meaningful.  Cons: a subdirectory then has a dependency on a parent directory which has some code smell.

Is there other options that I have not considered for where to place the main.go such that it won't force me to use a different package name?

Comment: Is the `denormalize` package intended to be used by other packages in addition to the one that creates the binary? If so, I think option 2 is best (although I would probably put the `main` package under `denormalize/cmd/denormalize` or something like that so the binary ends up being named `denormalize`). If it's only ever going to be a standalone binary, there's nothing wrong with having everything in the `main` package.

Comment: cmd/denormalize/main.go

Comment: Note that the package in directory `.../pkg` need not be named `pkg`. That being said, I agree with Volker.